# bug in qselect mips assembly program

Tags: assembly, mips, quickselect

Below is the quickselect algorithm in mips. There is an error there but I can't find it. qselect function does not work correctly, but the other functions seem to be fine. I have spent so many hours trying to debug it but it compiles without errors in mars. It just doesn't work as supposed

How I tested it:

```
n: .word 4
v: .word 3, 10, 8, 2
k: .word 2
correct: 8 but the program finds 2

n: .word 21
v: .word 10, 3, 7, 21, 20, 15, 14, 24, 9, 5, 1, 22, 16, 13, 12, 18, 4, 6, 19, 17, 2
k: .word 12
correct:15  but the program finds 19
```

```
swap: # swap entry point

la $t0, v   #t0 = address of v

sll $t1, $a0, 2     #t1 = 4*a0 = 4*i
add $t1, $t0 , $t1   #t1 = address of v[i]
lw $t2, 0($t1)  # t2=v[i]

sll $t3, $a1, 2     #t3 = 4*a1 = 4*j
add $t3, $t0 , $t3  #t3 = address of v[j]
lw $t4 , 0($t3)     #t4 = v[j]

sw $t4 , 0($t1)     #v[i] = v[j]
sw $t2, 0($t3) # v[j] = v[i]

jr      $ra         # return to caller


partition:
        addi $sp, $sp, -16              #adjust stack for 4 items
        sw $ra, 0($sp)                  #store ra in stack
        sw $s0, 4($sp)                  #store s0
        sw $a0, 8($sp)                  #store a0
        sw $a1, 12($sp)                 #store a1
        
        la $s0, v                       #load address of v0 in s0
        
        sll $t0, $a1, 2                 #t0 stores 4 * l
        add $t0, $t0, $s0               #t0 stores ad. of v[l]
        lw $t1, 0($t0)                  #t1 contains v[l] (t1 pivot)
        add $t2, $a0, $zero             #t2 is f (t2 i)
        add $t3, $a0, $zero             #t3 is f (t3 j)
        
for1:   slt $t4, $t3, $a1               #sets 1 to t4 if j < l
        beq $t4, $zero, exit            
        sll $t5, $t3, 2                 #t5 is 4 * j
        add $t5, $t5, $s0               #t5 stores ad. of v[j]
        lw $t6, 0($t5)                  #t6 has the value of v[j]
        
        slt $t4, $t6, $t1               #sets 1 to t4 if v[j] < pivot
        beq $t4, $zero, bfor
        
        add $a0, $t2, $zero             #a0 is i
        add $a1, $t3, $zero             #a1 is j
        
        addi $sp, $sp, -12              #adjust stack for 3 items
        sw $t1, 0($sp)
        sw $t2, 4($sp)
        sw $t3, 8($sp)                  #store pivot, i, j in stack
        jal swap                        #call swap
        
        lw $t1, 0($sp)
        lw $t2, 4($sp)
        lw $t3, 8($sp)                  #restores pivot, i, j before the call
        addi $sp, $sp, 12               #return items to stack
        
        lw $a1, 12($sp)                 #restore initial a1
        
        addi $t2, $t2, 1                #i++
        j bfor                          
        
bfor:   addi $t3, $t3, 1                #j++
        j for1                          #continue loop        
        
        
exit:   add $a0, $t2, $zero             #a0 is i
        addi $sp, $sp, -4               #adjust stack for 1 item
        sw $t2, 0($sp)                  #store i
        jal swap                        #calls swap
        lw $v0, 0($sp)                  #returns i
        addi $sp, $sp, 4                #returns item to stack
        
        lw $ra, 0($sp)                  #restore initial ra in stack
        lw $s0, 4($sp)                  #restore initial s0
        lw $a0, 8($sp)                  #restore initial a0
        lw $a1, 12($sp)                 #restore initial a1
        addi $sp, $sp, 16               #return items to stack

        jr      $ra
        
qselect:
    # a0 = f
    # a1 = l
    # a2 = k

    addi $sp, $sp, -4 #adjust stack for 1 item
    sw $ra, 0($sp)

 if1:
    #if !(f < 1+l) goto else0
    addi $t0, $a1, 1 #t0 = l+1
    slt $t0, $a0, $t0 #if f<1+l t0 = 1
    beq $t0, $zero, else0 # if t0 = 0 goto else0
    #j partition

 partition:  #int p = partition(f,l);
    jal partition #v0 becomes p
    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore ra
    #j if3

 if3:
    #if (p==k) goto else_if2 
    beq $v0, $a2,else_if2
    
 if2:  #if p < k return qselect(f,p-1,k);
    slt $t1, $a2, $v0 #if p > k, t1 = 1
    beq $t1, $zero, qselectp1lk # if t1 = 0 goto qselectp1lk
    #j qselectfp1k

 qselectfp1k:
    #return qselect(f,p-1,k);
    addi $a1, $a1, -1 # a1 = p-1
    jal partition
    lw $ra, 0($sp) # restore ra
    j end_qselect

 else0: #return v[f];
    la $t0, v # t0 = address of v
    sll $t1, $a0, 2 # t1 = 4*f
    add $t1, $t1, $t0 #t1 = address of v[f]
    lw $v0, 0($t1) #v0 = v[f]
    j end_qselect
 
 else_if2:
    #return v[k];
    la $t0, v # t0 = address of v
    sll $t1, $a2, 2 # t1 = 4*k
    add $t1, $t1, $t0 #t1 = address of v[k]
    lw $v0, 0($t1) #v0 = v[k]
    j end_qselect

 qselectp1lk: # return qselect(p+1,l,k);
    addi $a0, $v0, 1 # a0 = p+1
    jal qselect
    lw $ra, 0($sp) #restore ra
    j end_qselect

 end_qselect:
    lw $ra, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4 #restore stack
    jr $ra #return to caller
```

Comment: _"I have spent so many hours trying to debug it but it compiles without errors in mars"_. Well, getting the code to compile/assemble is a prerequisite to even start debugging. What have you done in terms of actual debugging once you got the code to run (e.g. stepping through your code)? What did you find during that debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
qselectfp1k:
    #return qselect(f,p-1,k);
    addi $a1, $a1, -1 # a1 = p-1   *** p is in $v0 so this is not p-1, but l-1
    jal partition                  *** this is supposed to be a call to qselect
    lw $ra, 0($sp) # restore ra
    j end_qselect
```

Did you notice that the comment says `return qselect(f,p-1,k)`, but the code calls `partition(f,l-1)` instead?

The usual Quickselect will have one call to the partition function and two recursive calls — but you have two calls to the partition function and one recursive call.

Comment: yes indeed I made those mistakes and I didn't even notice at all you are right. I would never have noticed. Unfortunately the code still doesn't work as intended

Comment: Run it in the debugger using single step.  Use the smallest possible input until that works, the enlarge the input.